# Unable to create custom mixin using ruby in compass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, compass-sass, compass

I am trying to add a custom compass function using ruby.
Here is my code. But finding hard to pick that function.

My folder structure

```
resources  
-- css  
-- extensions 
----- extension_name 
---------- stylesheets 
-------------- _extension_name.scss 
---------- templates 
---------- compass_init.rb
-- icons  
-- images  
-- sass  
----- something.scss
```

In compass_init.rb

```rb
require 'sass'
module WikiaFunctions
    def get_command_line_param(param_name, default_result='')
      result = ARGV.find {|arg| arg =~ /^#{param_name}=/} || default_result
      Sass::Script::String.new result.split(/=/).last 
    end
end

module Sass::Script::Functions
   include WikiaFunctionss
end
```

In my own Scss file something.scss

```scss
.test {
   display: block;
   background-color: get_command_line_param("logoColor", "white");
 }
```

But the out put of something.css is

```css
.test {
   display: block;
   background-color: get_command_line_param("logoColor", "white");
 }
```

What am i doing wrong here?
 Please guide me in getting this solved. Basically my compass version is in 0.12.7 and str_index, str_length and str_slice is not supported to make custom str_replace. So I wanted to build my own string functions.

I can't upgrade to compass version 1 or higher as my sencha touch application doesn't support it.
So I am planning to write my own ruby function but failing to do so.

Comment: I don't think the name of your .rb file is correct.  I'm fairly certain the name of the file has to be the same as the name of your extension.  What does your gemspec look like?

Comment: Those are the only files I have I mentioned in the directory. I also renamed it to same name as extension without working. gemspec was not created as part of  "compass create my_extension --using compass/extension -x scss".